# Textfield is having problems parsing its value?

Tags: php, html

So I got this form:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="secret" value=<?php echo getMyValue() ?> />
Name: <input type="text" name="txt" value=<?php echo getMyValue() ?> />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You see the text input element? The value is the result of `getMyValue()`. Such result is a line that contains HTML tags, like `<b> <i>` etc... And, apparently, when the text contains such tags, my text input breaks. If the text doesn't have such tags, everything is alright.

Any ideas to fix this parsing problem? (dunno if it is actually parsing the problem...)

---

**EDIT**
Here is the function's code:

```
function getMyValue()
{
$con = mysql_connect("myConnectionDataStuff");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("myUsername", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DATA");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  return $row["TEXT"];
  }

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value should be enclosed in quotes. It will enter everything properly if you enclose it in quotes, but the tags won't be parsed; they will simply be "as-is" in the text field.

Use this code instead:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="<?php echo getMyValue() ?>" />
    Name: <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo getMyValue() ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see exactly what getMyValue() is returning? Either post the source for that function, or post the *exact* output of it, HTML tags and all.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but that doesn't really help, seeing that I don't know what's returned by the query. Just echo the response onto a blank page and paste the source, please. Then we'll be able to tell what's going wrong when putting it into the textbox.

Comment: The echo result is **HELLO WORLD** (already bolded, tags have been parsed)

Comment: And the code I gave you doesn't work? I just tested it and it works fine for me...

Comment: A mistake. Now the textbox works properly. But I got a problem. The <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="<?php getMyValue() ?>"/> sends the string to welcome.php, where I echo it, but I get blank. Here's the echo part: <?php echo "$_POST[secret]"; ?>

Comment: This code: **<?php echo "$_POST[secret]"; ?>** should read: **<?php echo $_POST["secret"]; ?>**

Comment: Wait, are <img> tags any different? Because it breaks with that.

Comment: Nope.. If it works for other tags, it should work for <img>. What is the text that's breaking it?

Answer (score 3):

you could use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
Name: <input type="text" name="txt" 
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getMyValue(),ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
```

be aware if getMyValue() function returns single or double quote your input text will be broken.